# How to import a csv column with a dtype liste rather than str

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file.
One column is the list of the mean altitude of some town.
One of his element, for exemple, can be [571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649.0, 374.0]

When I do:

```
data=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=";", encoding="utf-8-sig",dtype={'Mean_Altitude':list})

a=data['Mean_Altitude'][0]
print a
print type(a)
```

I get:

```
[571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649.0, 374.0]
<type 'unicode'>
```

I would like to have a list of float.... Not a unicode or a string....

Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea.  Use `ast.literal_eval` in the `converters` parameter for `pd.read_csv`

Consider the string `txt` as our sample `csv`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import ast

txt = """A|Mean_Altitude|B
1|[571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649.0, 374.0]|X
2|[571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649.0, 374.0]|Y"""

converters = {'Mean_Altitude': ast.literal_eval}
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|', converters=converters)

print(df)

   A                                      Mean_Altitude  B
0  1  [571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649...  X
1  2  [571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649...  Y
```

`Mean_Altitude` is a column of lists

```
df.Mean_Altitude.loc[0][2]

600.0
```

And the `type`

```
type(df.Mean_Altitude.loc[0])

list
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer. However, when I try it, I got this error: File "<unknown>", line unknown ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing I have some "None" values it might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the []'s and then split the string on the `,`

```
s = '[571.0, 428.0, 600.0, 410.0, 588.0, 520.0, 649.0, 374.0]'
[float(substring) for substring in s[1:-1].split(', ')]
```

If you want to be really sure the string really is a list, you can check this with a regular expression